# Get all directories (hidden and non-hidden) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

What is the easiest way to get a list of all hidden and non-hidden directories (only directories) in a single call?

Obviously I can do it by connecting 2 different commands with `&&` like this:

```
ls -d ./.*/ && ls -d ./*/
```

but shouldn't there be a better way?

EDIT: I do not want the current directory to be included in the list.

Also, `ls -d ./.*/ ./*/` is a better alternative to what I have up there.

Comment: `ls -d ./.*/ ./*/`?

Comment: @Cyrus, ugh, you're right. I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `find` should do it:

```
find /some/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

`-maxdepth 1` ensures you don't descend into subdirectories. However, if that's what you want, you can just remove it.

`-mindepth 1` ensures `find` does not include the directory itself.

Comment: That works! but it also includes `.`. But that's not that much of a problem for my use case.

Comment: @BinHong Nothing that cannot be solved :) See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` you don't need to call any expternal utility to list all directories (including hidden ones). Just use:

```
# make sure we match entries starting with dot and return empty when list is empty
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

# print all the directories including ones starting with dot
printf '%s\n' */
```

Comment: Nice. `dotglob` is always an elegant addition whenever dot files are involved!

Comment: Might be worth noting that `ls` can be plugged in for `printf` if the custom formatting power of `printf` isn't needed (e.g. `ls -d */` ) ... as long as `dotglob` is enabled ;) Either way, this is the cleanest solution by far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `tree` command, you can get a nice view of your directories:

```
tree -a -d -L 3
```

where:

- a -> shows hidden and nonhidden
- d -> only shows directories
- L 3 -> limit depth (if you want infinite depth, simply remove this option)

Output example:

```
.
├── bin
├── Common
├── .git
│   ├── branches
│   ├── hooks
│   ├── info
│   ├── logs
│   │   └── refs
│   ├── objects
│   │   ├── 08
│   │   ├── 38
│   │   ├── 62
│   │   ├── 6f
│   │   ├── 8c
│   │   ├── 9e
│   │   ├── a0
│   │   ├── cb
│   │   ├── d9
│   │   ├── info
│   │   └── pack
│   └── refs
│       ├── heads
│       ├── remotes
│       └── tags
├── Setup
├── test
└── tools

27 directories
```

You also get the number of directories. If you do not want it, add the `--noreport` option.

It is also possible to exclude pattern etc... `man tree` is your friend there.

Another example: a flat list of directories, excluding `obj*` and `refs`

```
tree -a -d -L 3 -if -I "obj*|refs" --noreport
```

returns:

```
.
./bin
./Common
./.git
./.git/branches
./.git/hooks
./.git/info
./.git/logs
./Setup
./test
./tools
```

Comment: I included `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the file and it shows `./test.sh: line 9: tree: command not found`

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm more into looking for something already there but thanks for the answer nonetheless.